# How to replace values in select columns in R?

Tags: r

I have this table called `mydf`. I have hundreds of columns that start with 'ssd'. I need to grep these coulmns and convert the values in them to 0/0 if there is only one letter and 0/1 if there are two letters. I also need to skip the cells (do nothing with them) that have 'ND', blank cells, or anything other than the combination of 'A','T','G' and 'C' letters. the result table should look like `myresult`.

mydf

```
wws:ddf:xx  ssd:ddf:xx  sqt:ddf:xx  wws:dde:xy  ssd:dde:xy  sqt:dde:xy
               G                                     GA 
               GA                                    AT 
               GT                                       
               ND                                    GA 
               GT                                    TG 
               G                                     A
```

myresult

```
wws:ddf:xx  ssd:ddf:xx  sqt:ddf:xx  wws:dde:xy  ssd:dde:xy  sqt:dde:xy
              0/0                                   0/1 
              0/1                                   0/1 
              0/1                                           
              ND                                    0/1 
              0/1                                   0/1 
              0/0                                   0/0
```

Comment: It will help you get more (and quicker) responses in the future if you can put a way to easily reproduce your data in your question, rather than leave it to others to try to reproduce it from your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing the sample data with this code

```
mydf <-
  structure(list(`wws:ddf:xx` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
                 `ssd:ddf:xx` = c("G", "GA", "GT", "ND", "GT", "G"),
                 `sqt:ddf:xx` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
                 `wws:dde:xy` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
                 `ssd:dde:xy` = c("GA", "AT", "", "GA", "TG", "A"),
                 `sqt:dde:xy` = c("", "", "", "", "", "")),
            .Names = c("wws:ddf:xx", "ssd:ddf:xx", "sqt:ddf:xx", "wws:dde:xy", "ssd:dde:xy", "sqt:dde:xy"),
            row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I create a function to perform the changes in one column

```
change <- function(x) {
  # for ease, change all valid letters to digit 1
  y <- gsub("[ATGC]", "1", x)
  # count number of digits 1
  z <- sapply(strsplit(y, ""), function(x) sum(x=="1"))
  # corresponding text for number of digits (1 or 2), to be mapped later
  txt <- c("0/0", "0/1")
  # identify rows where digits 1 are found
  idx <- which(z>0)
  # if there's digit 1 replace with corresponding text in mapping above
  x[idx] <- txt[z[idx]]
  return(x)
}
```

Then identify columns that start with ssd

```
ssdcols <- grep("^ssd", names(mydf))
```

and apply the function to all such columns (saving as dataframe)

```
mydf[, ssdcols] <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydf[, ssdcols], change),
                                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Output as wanted

```
> mydf
  wws:ddf:xx ssd:ddf:xx sqt:ddf:xx wws:dde:xy ssd:dde:xy sqt:dde:xy
1                   0/0                              0/1           
2                   0/1                              0/1           
3                   0/1                                            
4                    ND                              0/1           
5                   0/1                              0/1           
6                   0/0                              0/0
```